Py4JError when using pyspark.sql.Row object in Dataframe
There are multiple relevant posts on this error but most have no answer, and the ones with answers have different context than mine.
Question: What may be causing the following error, and how can we fix it? The error occurs at line df = spark.createDataFrame([.....])
Remarks:

Error does not occur if I simply use df = spark.range(10) and it successfully displays data.
Python version 3.12, Spark: 3.3.4, PySpark: 3.3.4
java version "1.8.0_401", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_401-b10), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.401-b10, mixed mode)
I'm using VSCode as an editor on Windows10

Code:
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

import findspark
findspark.init()

from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0))
])

Error:
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 9
      6 from pyspark.sql import Row
      8 # df = spark.range(10)
----> 9 df = spark.createDataFrame([
     10     Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0))
     11 ])

File c:\VSCode_PyProjects\PySpark_Official_proj\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:1443, in SparkSession.createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1438 if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
   1439     # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
   1440     return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
   1441         data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema
   1442     )
-> 1443 return self._create_dataframe(
   1444     data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1445 )

File c:\VSCode_PyProjects\PySpark_Official_proj\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:1485, in SparkSession._create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
   1483     rdd, struct = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
   1484 else:
-> 1485     rdd, struct = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
   1486 assert self._jvm is not None
...
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

